# Convert dictionary of DataFrames to xarray DataArray?

Tags: pandas, python-xarray

Is there a fast method for this? I'm not quite getting that from the docs.

i.e. how to convert this to 3d xarray object with all the labels?

```py
d = {x: pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 3)) for x in [1,2,3]}

def dict_of_df_to_xarray(d, key_name=None):
    import xarray
    keys = list(sorted(d.keys()))
    df = d[keys[0]]
    ind = df.index
    if key_name is None:
        key_name = 'key'
    columns = df.columns
    index_name = df.index.name
    if index_name is None:
        index_name = 'index'
    column_name = df.columns.name
    if column_name is None:
        column_name = 'column'
    df = xarray.DataArray(np.concatenate([d[k].values[:, :, None] for k in keys], axis=2), dims=[index_name, column_name,
        key_name], coords={index_name: ind, column_name: columns, key_name: keys})
    return df
```

Comment: could you show an expample?

Comment: Yep, posted an example.

Comment: Something like `d2 = pd.concat([v for v in d.values()]).to_xarray()` maybe.

Comment: Yeah, I just posted the long way. The question is whether there is that method in xarray somewhere. There should be really.

Comment: `xr.Dataset(d).to_array()`?

Comment: @Maximilian bingo. Super easy when you know it I guess. You want to post it as an answer for SO points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier than it seems! Maybe we should add this to the docs...

```
xr.Dataset(d).to_array()
```

Comment: Yeah, it's one of those things that easy once you know. It does feel like a common path (dict of dataframes to xarray).